# component @input are not recognized under lazy loaded module context

Tags: angular, lazy-loading

I implemented a date component:

component:

```
import { Component, HostListener, AfterViewInit, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter, Input, ElementRef, forwardRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from '@angular/forms';

declare var $: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'date',
  templateUrl: './date.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./date.component.scss'],
  providers: [
  { 
    provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
    multi: true,
    useExisting: forwardRef(() => DateComponent),
  }
]
})
export class DateComponent  implements AfterViewInit,  ControlValueAccessor {

  public dateConstructionMessage = '';
  public innersize: number = window.innerWidth;
  public showHelpMessage = false;
  public formControlNameDate;
  //The internal data model for form control value access
  private innerValue: any = '';

  @Input() nameDate: string;
  @Input() patternDate: string;
  @Input() maskDate: string;
  //@Input() c:FormControl = new FormControl(); 

  @Output() selectCallBack = new EventEmitter<any>();
  @Output() closeCallBack = new EventEmitter<any>();
  @Output() sendLog = new EventEmitter<any>();
  @Output() focusDateField = new EventEmitter<any>();
  @Output() sendFormControlValue = new EventEmitter<any>();
```

html:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input style="width: 100%;" class="form-control" id="datepicker" type="text" (focus)="focusFunction()" placeholder="{{nameDate}}" title="{{nameDate}}" pattern="[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4}" mask="00/00/0000" (keyup)="onKeyUp($event)" #input (blur)="onChange($event, input.value)">
        </td>
        <td style="position : relative">
            <img id="help1" src="./../../assets/images/help.png" alt="Help" (mouseover)="showHelpMessage=true" (mouseout)="showHelpMessage=false" title="Format de date : dd/mm/aaaa,  exemple : 22/03/1980"> 
            <div *ngIf="showHelpMessage" style="position: absolute; top: -54px;left: -140px; width: 230px; background-color: #ECB605;padding: 5px 5px; border-radius: 6px;">
                Format de date : dd/mm/aaaa,  exemple : 22/03/1980
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This date component is included in a CoreModule:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    DateComponent,
    SimpleDialogComponent,
    DragDropDirective,
    DigitOnlyDirective,
    MultiplyCharacterPipe
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatButtonModule
    ],
exports: [DateComponent],
schemas: [
    CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA,
    NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA
  ]
})
export class CoreModule { }
```

This coreModule is included in the AppModule.
I use a lazy loaded module:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/homePage',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'homePage',
    component: HomePageComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'produitImmobilier',
    loadChildren: () => import('./produit-immobilier/produit-immobilier-routing.module').then(module => module.ProduitImmobilierRoutingModule)
  },
```

And further:

```
const routes: Routes = [
      {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'addProduitImmobilier',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'addProduitImmobilier',
    component: AddProduitImmobilierComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ProduitImmobilierModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class ProduitImmobilierRoutingModule { }
```

ET

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AddProduitImmobilierComponent,
    CropperDialogComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MatAutocompleteModule,
    MatFormFieldModule
  ]
})
export class ProduitImmobilierModule { }
```

and when I try to browse localhost:4200/produitImmobilier/addProduitImmobilier, I get the following  error

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'nameDate' since it isn't a known property of 'date'. ("onKeyUpCallback($event)" (focusDateField)="focusFunction($event)" (blur)="checkValidityFirstTab();" [ERROR ->][nameDate]="'Date de construction'"  c="{{dialogFormGroup.get(['dateConstruction']).value}}" [maskDat"): ng:///ProduitImmobilierModule/AddProduitImmobilierComponent.html@179:264
Can't bind to 'c' since it isn't a known property of 'date'. ("eld)="focusFunction($event)" (blur)="checkValidityFirstTab();" [nameDate]="'Date de construction'"  [ERROR ->]c="{{dialogFormGroup.get(['dateConstruction']).value}}" [maskDate]="'00/00/0000'" [patternDate]="'[0-"): ng:///ProduitImmobilierModule/AddProduitImmobilierComponent.html@179:301
Can't bind to 'maskDate' since it isn't a known property of 'date'. ("ab();" [nameDate]="'Date de construction'"  c="{{dialogFormGroup.get(['dateConstruction']).value}}" [ERROR ->][maskDate]="'00/00/0000'" [patternDate]="'[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4}'" formControlName="dateConstru"): ng:///ProduitImmobilierModule/AddProduitImmobilierComponent.html@179:357
Can't bind to 'patternDate' since it isn't a known property of 'date'. ("e construction'"  c="{{dialogFormGroup.get(['dateConstruction']).value}}" [maskDate]="'00/00/0000'" [ERROR ->][patternDate]="'[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4}'" formControlName="dateConstruction" (sendFormControlVal"): ng:///ProduitImmobilierModule/AddProduitImmobilierComponent.html@179:383
'date' is not a known element:
1. If 'date' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. To allow any element add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("
                                </td>
                                <td style="width:22.5%">
                                    [ERROR ->]<date (selectCallBack)="onSelectDateConstructionDatePickerCallBack($event)" (closeCallBack)="onCloseD"): ng:///ProduitImmobilierModule/AddProduitImmobilierComponent.html@179:9
Can't bind to 'nameDate' since it isn't a known property of 'date'. ("onKeyUpCallback($event)" (focusDateField)="focusFunction($event)" (blur)="checkValidityFirstTab();" [ERROR ->][nameDate]="'Date de construction'"  [maskDate]="'00/00/0000'" [patternDate]="'[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0"): ng:///ProduitImmobilierModule/AddProduitImmobilierComponent.html@265:270
Can't bind to 'maskDate' since it isn't a known property of 'date'. ("eld)="focusFunction($event)" (blur)="checkValidityFirstTab();" [nameDate]="'Date de construction'"  [ERROR ->][maskDate]="'00/00/0000'" [patternDate]="'[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4}'" formControlName="dateConstru"): ng:///ProduitImmobilierModule/AddProduitImmobilierComponent.html@265:307
Can't bind to 'patternDate' since it isn't a known property of 'date'. (")" (blur)="checkValidityFirstTab();" [nameDate]="'Date de construction'"  [maskDate]="'00/00/0000'" [ERROR ->][patternDate]="'[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4}'" formControlName="dateConstruction" (sendFormControlVal"): ng:///ProduitImmobilierModule/AddProduitImmobilierComponent.html@265:333
'date' is not a known element:
1. If 'date' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. To allow any element add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("
                            <tr>
                                <td style="width:40%">
                                    [ERROR ->]<date date1 (selectCallBack)="onSelectDateConstructionDatePickerCallBack($event)" (closeCallBack)="on"): ng:///ProduitImmobilierModule/AddProduitImmobilierComponent.html@265:9
```

The html part of AddProduitImmobilierComponent is the following:

```
                    <td style="width:22.5%">
                            <date (selectCallBack)="onSelectDateConstructionDatePickerCallBack($event)" (closeCallBack)="onCloseDateConstructionDatePickerCallBack($event)" (sendLog)="onKeyUpCallback($event)" (focusDateField)="focusFunction($event)" (blur)="checkValidityFirstTab();" [nameDate]="'Date de construction'"  c="{{dialogFormGroup.get(['dateConstruction']).value}}" [maskDate]="'00/00/0000'" [patternDate]="'[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4}'" formControlName="dateConstruction" (sendFormControlValue)="updateDateConstructionValue($event)"></date>
                        </td>
```

Comment: You need to import the module in the lazy loaded module. Always import declarations in the module you want to use them in. They are not transitive (unlike Injectables, they are transitive). So in your case, you need to import it in the `ProduitImmobilierModule`. On a side note, I strongly suggest creating a `shared` module for this. Usually, `Core` is used for a module that is only imported in your `AppModule`, whereas `Shared` is used to indicate it can be imported in every Module (=> shared) throughout your application.

Comment: Thank you pascalpuetz, I resolved the issue. See the answer

Answer (score 0):

Finally I resolved my issue

Here is the AppModule

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomePageComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    NgxMaskModule.forRoot(),
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
```

Here is the shared module

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    DateComponent,
    SimpleDialogComponent,
    DragDropDirective,
    DigitOnlyDirective,
    MultiplyCharacterPipe
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatInputModule
    ],
    exports: [
    DateComponent,
    SimpleDialogComponent,
    DragDropDirective,
    DigitOnlyDirective,
    MultiplyCharacterPipe,
    CommonModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatInputModule
        ],
    schemas: [
        CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA,
        NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA
      ]
})
export class Shared1Module { }
```

Here is the AppRouting module

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/homePage',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'homePage',
    component: HomePageComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'produitImmobilier',
    loadChildren: () => import('./produit-immobilier/produit-immobilier-routing.module').then(module => module.ProduitImmobilierRoutingModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'account',
    loadChildren: () => import('./user-account/user-account-routing.module').then(module => module.UserAccountRoutingModule)
  }
  ];


@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Here is the ProduitImmobilierRoutingModule module

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'list',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'add',
    component: AddProduitImmobilierComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'list',
    component: ListProduitImmobilierComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'details/:id',
    component: ProduitImmobilierDetailsComponent
  },
  { path: '**', component: ListProduitImmobilierComponent }  
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ProduitImmobilierModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class ProduitImmobilierRoutingModule { }
```

Here is the ProduitImmobilierModule

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AddProduitImmobilierComponent,
    CropperDialogComponent,
    ListProduitImmobilierComponent,
    ProductLightComponent,
    ProduitImmobilierDetailsComponent,
    UserCardComponent],
    
  imports: [
    Shared1Module,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MatAutocompleteModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    ImageCropperModule,
    MDBBootstrapModule.forRoot(),
    AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
      apiKey: 'AIzaSyA3nptWFYQVNZFsBws0egtBoEzbv-Qye_Q'
    })
  ],
  entryComponents: [CropperDialogComponent]
})
export class ProduitImmobilierModule { }
```